# Procedure for Arithmetic (Division) in tcl

Tags: scripting, tcl

Need to divide two numbers (can be floating) in tcl and check if the number is an exact multiple.

`!($x % $y)` doesn't work as the operand expects integers.

Comment: There is the `fmod()` math function in `expr`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: ::tcl::mathfunc::fmod 1.806 0.258 returns 0.0. Is there an error with the usage?

Answer (score 2):

Many floating point numbers used on computers are just an approximation of the specified value. So expecting to be able to check if one value is an exact multiple of another value will likely lead to disappointment.

For example: `expr {fmod(1, 0.1)}` => 0.09999999999999995 because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point format.

I'm afraid you will have to reconsider your requirements.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Comment: Is it not possible to divide the two numbers and check if that result is a whole number?

Comment: Due to the used approximations, that will not always produce the "correct" answer. Example: `expr {0.3 / 0.1}` => 2.9999999999999996. So you will have to settle for some margin within which you will call something a multiple.